# kubernetes and etcd: No action, but the metric "etcd_server_slow_apply_total" increases to 40

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, etcd

etcd version:

```json
{"etcdserver":"3.3.10","etcdcluster":"3.3.0"}
```

My understanding is that `etcd_server_slow_apply_total` is related to add, delete or update on disk that is handled slowly.

We didn't do anything Kubernetes and etcd; the pod didn't restart. Why did `delta(etcd_server_slow_apply_total{project="XX"}[3m])` increase to 40?

See this screen shot for illustration:

[image: screenshot showing the high value]

Comment: your image is not dsiplaying. perhaps edit the question.

Comment: Picture:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/84nYj.png

Comment: I think, new users have to wait like 24 hours before pictures become visible. I can see the image link in the question. see if you can make it appear. some syntax has to be updated to make it show.

Comment: Hi, what platform/infrastructure are you running your k8s cluster on? Which k8s version?

Comment: k8s version: 1.5
infrastructure: private cloud